# Matrices and Vectors LINGO

Tags: optimization

I am working in LINGO software. I have two matrices X and Y with different sizes. I need to write all the elements of the two matrices in one unit vector Z. Did any one encountered such a case before and was able to do it?

Comment: There is no standard term for this. Don't be ashamed to simply explain it in words.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am working in LINGO software

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense. I'll leave it to someone else to answer then.

Comment: I would write it as vec([$x$,$y$]) (divided by the norm of itself for the unit length)